# passport validity for travel to China

Tags: paperwork, china, passport-renewals, visa-expiration

I have Chinese visa valid up to 14th Feb 2020 and I am entering China in 12th February for 6 days and coming back.

My passport expires in 24th April 2020  can I travel on same passport ?

Comment: What nationality passport do you travel on? (It does not always make a difference but it can be important.)

Comment: Isn't it the visa expiry that's relevant here? If you're entering on the 12th and stay 6 days, then you intend to leave past the expiry of your visa, right?

Comment: Does the visa say "Enter Before" or does it say "Valid Until?"

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica: Chinese visas say "Enter Before", and only need to be valid on the date of entry.

Comment: In theory yes, but always beware in china things changes fast and rules are not always communicated clearly so I would never risk it, but that’s just me I like to be on the safe side

Answer (score 1):

Some countries requires travelers' passports to be valid on arrival, some that their passports be valid for a specific period after the time of expected travel. Conceivably, some countries might specify different time periods depending upon the nationality or country of residence of the traveler. Countries through which you transit to get to China may, in addition, also have their own passport validity requirements. You haven't disclosed any of these specifics.

Airlines use the [Timatic database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) to assess the sufficiency of a traveler's documentation. Many Timatic portals are available to users; [here's one](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html).

Querying Timatic about a no-transit entry to China by a national of a random half-dozen countries consistently yields this:

> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid on arrival.

A more specific answer can be given if you specify your nationality, and if different, your country of residence, as well as the country(ies) through which you'll transit to get to China.

Comment: It's also important to remember that countries you connect via may have different rules, and may require 3 or 6 months validity even if your destination doesn't.

Comment: @Doc Exactly right, thanks. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: **WARNING** There is currently a TIMATIC inconsistency: it says that for entry, it must only be valid on arrival, but for transit, it has to have 3 months left. Makes no sense obviously, and it is pending review.

Comment: Also, to do a general search rather than having to insert a random nationality, just go here https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html, select China, Passport and Document validity

Comment: @Crazydre As to the underlying question: the OP says the destination is China. I think we all assume that China is not a transit location...but I agree it could be.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The team has a lot going on, so all my review requests are stored in a "backlog". Sent my contact person a summary of dozens of suspected/certain errors in November, with this inconsistency being the second most important one

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I'm saying it could be a requirement that the passport has 3 months, but that the Chinese authorities were sloppy in communicating changes to IATA (happens a lot with other countries). This is because how it's stated now makes zero sense

Comment: @Crazydre Yes, that could be the case as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103442/discussion-between-crazydre-and-davidsupportsmonica).